Problems when setting up the environment (Angular)
I followed this tutorial https://angular.dev/tools/cli/setup-local to set up local environment and workspace (Angular).
The npm version was 10.9.0 and node version was 22.11.0
Everything went smoothly until I run this line ng new new_project on my terminal. The problem was like the image attached and I didn't know how to fix this problem (although I asked the ChatGPT for clarification).

Do you know how to fix this problem? Thank you so much!

I cannot reproduce, for me running the same command with the same npm/Node version works

check your network for any kind of blocker or use --f :)

As of me issue happen due to cache.
npm cache verify

then try:
npm cache clean --force
npm install –g @angular/cli@latest 
ng new <YourProjectName>

